# How to solve gamma function NaN warning in R program for logistic growth equation?

Tags: methods, numeric, calculus

I'm trying to write an R program to solve to numerically the logistic growth equation of fractional order (in sense Caputo Derivate), using the Grunwald Letnikov method but I always get the `gamma(alpha+1-k) NaNs produced` warning. I don't know why because `(alpha+1-k)` is supposed to be very small but not zero. Here is the code:

```r
h<-0.01
t1<-1
tf<-20
t<- seq(t1, tf, by = h)

q<-1  #Orden de la derivada
a<-0.5
k1<-15
x1o <- 1.5
f1 <- function(x1,a,k1){a*x1*(1-x1/k1)};
x1 <- numeric()
x1[1] <- x1o
for (i in 1: (length(t)-1)){
  k=1:i;
  x1[i+1] = h^(-q) * f1(x1[i],a,k1) + sum((-1)^(k+1) * (gamma(q+1)/ ( gamma(k+1)* gamma(q-k+1))) * x1[i-k])
}
```